# <asp:PlaceHolder> alternate in mvc Razor page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I am using razor page in .net core 2.1. In .aspx we can use `<asp:PlaceHolder>` and write some logic inside it and we can hide or show this placeholder in our .cs class but I wonder how can we achieve this in Razor page? I can't see any option like placeholder in @Html. I want to create two placeholder and based on some condition in my .cs class I want to hide one and show another one. Also I don't want to make an ajax call. I know this is achievable by creating a div and set display none initially and show the div based on ajax response but is it possible without an ajax call?

Comment: Only if you were to include all the html in the hidden `<div>` elements and then display the relevant one using javascript

Comment: In Razor you can use `@if` to render something based on some condition, would that work? See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-2.1#control-structures)

Comment: @HansKeﬆing, yeah using if is a good idea. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To conditionally render some html in Razor syntax, you can use various [control structures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-2.1#control-structures), like

```
@if (value % 2 == 0)
{
    <p>The value was even.</p>
}
else if (value >= 1337)
{
    <p>The value is large.</p>
}
else
{
    <p>The value is odd and small.</p>
}
```